# Woocommerce how to change the URL before proceeding to checkout

Tags: redirect, woocommerce, hook-woocommerce, woocommerce-theming

I need to capture some information for a particular product category.

I am thinking is there a way I can change the proceed to checkout link to go to a custom URL (which will be a booking form with an action of going to the checkout page on submit) if the product category is in the cart.

I am a developer but in Java so do not know the structure and hooks very well but am sure I can get it together if

- a) it is possible.
- B) someone can help me which files to modify.

Thanks guys

Answer (score 1):

I have fixed this by adding a filter on checkout:

```php
add_filter('woocommerce_get_checkout_url', 'booking_redirect_checkout');
```